# Using an attribute as argument of a method of the same class

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I want to define an attribute of a class and then use it as argument of a method in the same class in the following way

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self,attr):
        self.attr=attr
    def method1(self,x=self.attr):
        return 2*x
```

It returns an error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

How can I define the method in such a way that whenever I don't write `x` explicitly it just uses the attribute `attr` ?

In the example, what I mean is that I would like to have

```
cl=Class1()
print cl.method1(12) # returns '24'
cl.attr= -2
print cl.method1() # returns '-4'
```

Comment: Couldn't you just set a default value, and if the argument is equal to the default then assign the result of `self.attr` ?

Comment: you have to define `attr` within the method1 to make use of it and you can remove the `x=self.attr` as an arg that's defining the x to it's address location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in method1, you just define the `self` variable in the first argument. And the self variable will only useable in the function body.
You probably think `self` is a special keyword. Actually `self` is just anormal varialbe like any variable else.

To solve the issue:
Use default value in function defination and check it in the function body:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 3

    def method1(self, x=None):
        x = self.attr if x is None else x
        return 2*x


cl = Class1()
print(cl.method1(12))
cl.attr=-2
print(cl.method1())
```

Result:

```
24
-4
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code it seems like you are naming x as an argument you are passing to the function when in reality you are giving the **init** function the value, try the following code:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self,attr = 3):
        self.attr=attr
    def method1(self):
        y = (self.attr)*(2)
        return y
```

When you call the function you should do it like this:

```
result = Class1(4)
print(result.method1())

>>8
```

P.T. Im kind of new in Python so don't give my answer for granted or as if it's the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: My issue is that I want to still be able to give `method1` some other argument outside the class when needed.

Comment: Like an n amount of numbers to multiplicate?, if that's the case you should be using the *args syntax inside the __init__ function.

Comment: I want to just write `cl.method1()` when the argument is meant to be `self.attr` but also be able to write the argument explicitly in any other case. (I see that below someone has given a possible solution).